# Haxe sys.db.Manager - SQLite - "Invalid field:__cache__"

Tags: sqlite, haxe

Trying to use SQLite with Haxe. Any SPOD manager function throws an error:

```
Invalid field:__cache__
```

Using Haxe 3.1.3, compiling for cpp target on Mac OS X.

```
class Main {

    var cnx:Connection;

    public function new()  {

        cnx = sys.db.Sqlite.open(Assets.getPath("db/main.db"));
        sys.db.Manager.cnx = cnx;
        sys.db.Manager.initialize();

        var u = Players.manager.get(1);
        trace(u);

        sys.db.Manager.cleanup();
        cnx.close();
    }
}

class Players extends sys.db.Object{
    public static var manager = new sys.db.Manager<Players>(Players);

    public var id : SId;
    public var username : SString<32>;
    public var x : SInt;
    public var y : SInt;
}
```

Comment: Which line is causing the error? If you compile with -debug you might also get a stack trace that could help debug the problem.

Comment: Application compiles without problem, only when I run it, I get the following output to console: "Invalid field:__cache__" (same with -debug flag). Anything else. The line causing the problem is "var u = Players.manager.get(1);", so I suppose, it has something to do with Manager.hx class ('cause it has "__cache__" value in one field), but I chechked it's code and didn't find anything wrong yet...

Comment: Hi, I tried to reproduce this, and this gist has exactly what I compiled: https://gist.github.com/jasononeil/74f814dbe0d9fa69b18d ... Do you get an error compiling this exact code? Because I don't... I'm compiling on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 64bit)

Comment: BTW, that was with Haxe 3.1.3, and hxcpp 3.1.39, no other libraries installed.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked the same, BUT only if there is no record in DB with id I'm trying to get. So if I do "var u = Players.manager.get(1);" and record with id=1 is in DB, it throws exception: "Invalid field:__cache__" and program quits. If record isn't there, it returns null, no exception.

I'm trying to compile with OpenFL 2,0,1, Haxe 3.1.3, hxcpp 3.1.39 for Mac OS X (64 bit)

Comment: possible duplicate of [AS3-Spod Example or tutorial? or any other AS3 ORM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815780/as3-spod-example-or-tutorial-or-any-other-as3-orm)